# Update table using values from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, join, update

I have 2 table in my database.

Table #1

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | family | phone | email | gender | phone2 | address | birthdate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table #2

```
-----------------------------------------
| gender | address | phone | birthdate |
-----------------------------------------
```

in table #1 columns **address** and **phone2** is empty and columns **gender** and **birthdate** values is same as table #2.

How can I read data from table #2 and update **address** and **phone2** in table #1 with values from table #2 **address** and **phone** columns when **gender** and **birthdate** is the same in each row?

for example:
this is some data in Table #1

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | family | phone | email | gender | phone2 | address | birthdate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| john | doe    | 12345| t@t.com| Male  |         |         | 1980-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| mike | clark  | 65432| x@y.com| Male  |         |         | 1990-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sara | King   | 875465| a@b.com|Female|         |         | 1970-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and here is some data in table #2

```
-----------------------------------------
| gender | address | phone | birthdate  |
-----------------------------------------
| Male   | 1704test|0457852|1980-01-01  |
-----------------------------------------
| Female | 1705abcs|0986532|1970-01-01  |
-----------------------------------------
| Male   | 1602cyzd|0326589|1990-01-01  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to update table #1 with data from table #2 and check **gender** and **birthdate** and make table #1 like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | family | phone | email | gender | phone2 | address | birthdate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| john | doe    | 12345| t@t.com| Male   |0457852 |1704test | 1980-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| mike | clark  | 65432| x@y.com| Male   |0326589  |1602cyzd| 1990-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sara | King   | 875465| a@b.com|Female |0986532  |1705abcs| 1970-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Comment: And what if there are 2 or more people with same gender and birthdate? Which phone and address (of the many) should be copied?

Comment: its not possible, this is just test table, in my real data its not possible to same person have same values.

Comment: If it is really not possible, i.e. if there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `table2 (gender, birthdate)`, you should add that info in the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to achieve your desired results.

**Undeterministic methods**

(in the event that many rows in table 2 match one in table 1)

```
UPDATE T1
SET    address = T2.address,
       phone2 = T2.phone
FROM   #Table1 T1
       JOIN #Table2 T2
         ON T1.gender = T2.gender
            AND T1.birthdate = T2.birthdate
```

Or a slightly more concise form

```
UPDATE #Table1
SET    address = #Table2.address,
       phone2 = #Table2.phone
FROM   #Table2
WHERE  #Table2.gender = #Table1.gender
       AND #Table2.birthdate = #Table1.birthdate
```

Or with a CTE

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT T1.address AS tgt_address,
                T1.phone2  AS tgt_phone,
                T2.address AS source_address,
                T2.phone   AS source_phone
         FROM   #Table1 T1
                INNER JOIN #Table2 T2
                  ON T1.gender = T2.gender
                     AND T1.birthdate = T2.birthdate)
UPDATE CTE
SET    tgt_address = source_address,
       tgt_phone = source_phone
```

**Deterministic methods**

`MERGE` would throw an error rather than accept non deterministic results

```
MERGE #Table1 T1
USING #Table2 T2
ON T1.gender = T2.gender
   AND T1.birthdate = T2.birthdate
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET address = T2.address,
             phone2 = T2.phone;
```

Or you could pick a specific record if there is more than one match

With `APPLY`

```
UPDATE T1
SET    address = T2.address,
       phone2 = T2.phone
FROM   #Table1 T1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   #Table2 T2
                    WHERE  T1.gender = T2.gender
                           AND T1.birthdate = T2.birthdate
                    ORDER  BY T2.PrimaryKey) T2
```

.. Or a CTE

```
WITH T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender, birthdate ORDER BY primarykey) AS RN
         FROM   #Table2)
UPDATE T1
SET    address = T2.address,
       phone2 = T2.phone
FROM   #Table1 T1
       JOIN T2
         ON T1.gender = T2.gender
            AND T1.birthdate = T2.birthdate
            AND T2.RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TS
SET TS.TaskFullAddress = L.FullAddress
FROM [dbo].[TaskOrders]   TS
INNER JOIN Locations L
ON  TS.ClientId  = L.ClientId;
```